# How can I make use an array in a method that has parameter of a file directory and that returns an array in another python file?

Tags: python, file, directory

Below is the method that takes in source directory as method parameter and it returns an array. 
What this method is doing is to go to the source directory of the word documents, extract information of all word documents and then store them in an array. The method then return this array consists of lists of word documents.

The problem is how do I use the returned array and call the method in another python file? Please do help, thanks!! :((

```
def get_ednotes(str2):
    directory = str2
    my_text = docx2txt.process(directory)
    #path = 'C:\\Users\\L31307\\PycharmProjects\\FYP\\keys1.txt'
    path = "..\keys1.txt"
    ED_Notes_file = open(path, 'r')
    key_list = ED_Notes_file.read().split(':')
    my_text = my_text.replace('\n', '')
    my_text = my_text.replace('\xa0', '')
    new = my_text.split('Created By')
    new.pop(0)
    word = "Created By"
    new2 = [word + x for x in new]
    def find_between(s, first, last):
        try:
            start = s.index(first) + len(first)
            end = s.index(last, start)
            if(end !=2):
                return s[start:end]
            else:
                return'NA'
        except ValueError:
            return "NA"
    # print(len(new2))
    split = []
    key_list = ['Created By :', 'Created On :', 'Stage :', 'Notes :'] * len(new2)
    for i in new2:
        a = find_between(i, key_list[0], key_list[1])
        a = a.replace(':','')
        split.append(a)
        b = find_between(i, key_list[1], key_list[2])
        b = b.replace(':','')
        split.append(b)
        c = find_between(i, key_list[2], key_list[3])
        c = c.replace(':', '')
        split.append(c)
        d = i.split("Notes:", 1)[1]
        split.append(d)
    x = 0

    final_objects = []

    n = int(len(split)/4)
    for i in range(0, n):
        result = make_student(split[x], split[x+1], split[x+2], split[x+3])
        x = x+4
        final_objects.append(result)

    getFilenameOnly = os.path.basename(directory)
    #docNumber = ('_'.join(getFilenameOnly.split('_')[:1]))
    categoryType = ('_'.join(getFilenameOnly.split('_')[1:3]))
    result = {}
    count = 0
    dic = {}
    array = []
    arr_cat = []
    arr_new = []
    for i in final_objects:
        count = count + 1
        s = str(count)
        value = []
        value2 = []
        #dic['Created By'] = i.Created_By
        #dic['Created On'] = i.Created_On
        #dic['Stage'] = i.Stage
        dic['Notes'] = i.Notes
        s = dict(dic)
        array.append(s)
    final_list = {'Category': categoryType, 'Notes': array}
    arr_new += [final_list]
    dict2str = str(final_list)
    c = cleanString(newstring=dict2str)
    arr_cat += [c]
    new_arr = []
    for i in range(0, len(arr_cat)):
        r = '|'.join(str(arr_cat[i]).split(" ", 1))
    new_arr += [r]
    # open file to append the items in the array to the previously written textfile
    with open('ED_Notes.txt', 'a') as append_txtfile:
        for item in new_arr:
            append_txtfile.write("%s\n" % item)
    return new_arr

root_dir = "../dataprep/source_documents"

for filename in os.listdir(root_dir):
    str2 = root_dir + '/' + filename
    get_ednotes(str2)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you may do this

file1.py:

```
def get_ednotes(str2):
    directory = str2
    my_text = docx2txt.process(directory)
    ...
```

file2.py:

```
from file1 import get_ednotes

root_dir = "../dataprep/source_documents"

for filename in os.listdir(root_dir):
    str2 = root_dir + '/' + filename
    arr = get_ednotes(str2)
    print arr
```